# Duplicate Images when uploading using Wordpress REST api

Tags: ios, swift, wordpress, rest, alamofire

I am using Wordpress REST Api's that came out with Wordpress 4.7.
This issue I am experiencing only happens once in a while. 
I am using swift & Alamofire to call the REST Api.

If I try to upload multiple images using the http://website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media endpoint, it will duplicate some of the images.

When I check the Wordpress media Library, the images that are the duplications are named the exact same name. Does this mean its a WordPress issue?

Below is the code I'm using.

```
WordPressHelper().getAccessCode { (accessString, error) in
        if error != nil {
            completionHelper(nil, error)
        } else {
            let cilentsName = "\(jobsite.firstName) \(jobsite.lastName)'s"

            let endpoint = "http://website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/?access_token=\(accessString)"

            let parameters = [
                "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=appImage.jpg",
                "description": "Image from My app",
                "media_type": "image"
            ]


            let mgr = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
            mgr.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
                multipartFormData.append(image, withName: "file", fileName: "\(cilentsName) image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")

                for (key, value) in parameters {

                    multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
            }, to: endpoint, encodingCompletion: { (encodingResult) in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):

                    upload.response(completionHandler: { (dataResponse) in
                        do {

                            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResponse.data!, options: .allowFragments)
                            print("success \(json)")
                            completionHelper(json as? NSDictionary, nil)

                        } catch let error as NSError{
                            completionHelper(nil, error)
                        }
                    })

                case .failure(_):
                    let error = NSError(domain:"encodingError", code:-1, userInfo:
                        [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:"failure trying to upload image."])
                    print("failure \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    completionHelper(nil, error)
                }
            })

        }

    }
```